# Задача "Календарь на месяц"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Условие:

> Написать цикл, перед которым с клавиатуры прочитать номер месяца и года
>   Распечатать на экран этот месяц, каждую неделю с понедельника
>   Воскресенья выделять квадратными скобками

Моя неудачная реализация:

```
import datetime

myDate = list(map(int, input().split()))
myDateFirstWeekday = datetime.datetime(myDate[0], myDate[1], 1).weekday() + 1
monthsDays = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
if myDate[0] % 400 == 0 or (myDate[0] % 4 == 0 and myDate[0] % 100 != 0):
    monthsDays[2] += 1

weekList = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']
print(*weekList, sep=" ")

weekList = list()
if myDateFirstWeekday > 1:
        weekList.append('   ' * (myDateFirstWeekday - 1))
sun = ''
weekDays = myDateFirstWeekday
days = monthsDays[myDate[1]]
for i in range(days):
    if weekDays % 7 != 0:
        weekList.append(i + 1)
        weekDays += 1
    else:
        sun = '[' + str(i + 1) + ']'
        weekList.append(sun)
        print(*weekList, sep=' ')
        print(end='')
        weekDays = 1
        weekList = list()
if weekDays > 1:
    print(*weekList, sep=' ')
```

на выходе:

```
2020 3
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   [1]
2 3 4 5 6 7 [8]
9 10 11 12 13 14 [15]
16 17 18 19 20 21 [22]
23 24 25 26 27 28 [29]
30 31
```

можно ли как-то выводить на печать в одну строку, не загоняя предварительно в список? 
как учесть кол-во пробелов если дата 1 знак и 2 знака?

Comment: `python -m calendar 2020 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация вполне удачная, нужно просто немного доработать напильником.

Чтобы не загонять все в список, можно просто делать `print` вместо `append`.

Чтобы выровнять столбцы дат можно воспользоватся форматированием строк: например,
`'{:<2}'.format(1)` превратится в строку `'1 '` (число в строке форматирования показывает требуемую "ширину" результата, угловая скобка - направление выравнивания). Кратко про форматирование строк с помощью метода `format`: https://habr.com/post/236633/

Получается примерно так:

```
weekList = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']
print(*weekList, sep=' ')

if myDateFirstWeekday > 1:
    print('   ' * (myDateFirstWeekday - 1), end='')

weekDays = myDateFirstWeekday
days = monthsDays[myDate[1]]
for i in range(days):
    if weekDays % 7 != 0:
        print('{:<2}'.format(i + 1), end=' ')        
    else:
        print('[' + str(i + 1) + ']')
    weekDays += 1

# Перенос строки, если последняя неделя месяца не заканчивается на воскресенье:
if weekDays % 7 != 1:
    print()

print(*weekList, sep=' ')
```

Убрал обнуление ("объединичивание") номера дня недели каждое воскресенье, т.к. день недели в цикле и так проверяется как остаток от деления на 7. Последнее условие не очень понятно зачем было нужно, просто оставил чтобы снизу дни недели всегда выводились.

Сентябрь 2018:

```
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
               1  [2]
3  4  5  6  7  8  [9]
10 11 12 13 14 15 [16]
17 18 19 20 21 22 [23]
24 25 26 27 28 29 [30]
31 
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
```

Февраль 2021:

```
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
1  2  3  4  5  6  [7]
8  9  10 11 12 13 [14]
15 16 17 18 19 20 [21]
22 23 24 25 26 27 [28]
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 2):

> как учесть кол-во пробелов если дата 1 знак и 2 знака?

[string — format specification mini-language — Python 3.4.9 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> можно ли как-то выводить на печать в одну строку, не загоняя предварительно в список?

Вопрос не понятен. Язык позволяет удобно оперировать сразу списками, а не их значениями. Можно не загонять в список, а сразу его получить. Можно, сразу составить шаблонную строку `'{} {} {} [{}]'.format(a, b, c, d)`, можно совместить:

```
first_weekday = 6
days = [str(d) for d in range(1, 31+1)]
fake = [''] * first_weekday
days = fake + days
templ = '{:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} [{:>2}]'
for i in range(0, len(days), 7):
    week_days = days[i: i+7]
    print_str = templ.format(*week_days) if len(week_days) == 7 else ' '.join(week_days)
    print(print_str)
```

Что дает такой результат:

```
                  [ 1]
 2  3  4  5  6  7 [ 8]
 9 10 11 12 13 14 [15]
16 17 18 19 20 21 [22]
23 24 25 26 27 28 [29]
30 31
```